# employee class will not calculate correctly

Tags: java, class, joptionpane

for the assignment, an employee has a ID number, hourly wage and works a certain # of hours. i need to calculate the gross income from those 2 values and then based of that there is withholding from the pay, in my code i believe all that is there but when i test my program i can only calculate the pay that was earned, the withholding and net pay come as a value of 0. i would appreciate any help on the issue, thank you.

```
// an employee has an ID, get paid an amout hourly and work an amount of hours

// tax is withheld depending on gross pay

public class Employee

{

//withholding calculation

public Employee(String empId, double hrsWrk, double hrPay)
{
    employeeId = empId;
    hoursWorked = hrsWrk;
    hourlyPay = hrPay;

}

// access methods
public String getEmployeeId()
{
    return employeeId;
}

public double getHoursWorked()
{
    return hoursWorked;
}

public double getHourlyPay()
{
    return hourlyPay;
}

public double getWithholding()
{
    return withholding;
}

public double getIncome()
{
    double income = hourlyPay * hoursWorked;
    return income;
}

public double getNetPay()
{
    double netPay = income - withholding;
    return netPay;
}



// mutator methods
public void setId(String empId)
{
    employeeId = empId;
}

public void setHoursWorked(double hrsWrk)
{
    hoursWorked = hrsWrk;
}

public void setHourlyPay(double hrPay)
{
    hourlyPay = hrPay;
}

//withholding calculator based on income
public void calcWithholding()
{
    if(income <= 0)
    {
        withholding = 0.0;
    }

    else if(income >0 && income <= 300.0)
        withholding = income*10.0/100;

    else if(income >= 300.01 && income <= 400.0)
        withholding = income*12/100;

    else if(income >= 400.01 && income <= 500.0)
        withholding = income*15/10;

    else
        withholding = income*20/100;

        System.out.println("withholding is " + withholding);
}

public void displayWithholding()
{


    calcWithholding();
    System.out.println("Employee " + employeeId + " your income is " + getIncome() + " per week\n you have to pay " + getWithholding());
    System.out.println("Employee " + employeeId + " your net income is " + getNetPay());
}


//instance fields
private String employeeId;
private double hoursWorked;
private double hourlyPay;
private double withholding;
private double income;
private double netPay;
}


here is the test program---------------------------------------------

    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class EmployeeTest
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{



    String employeeId = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your Employee ID");


    String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your hourly wage");
    double hourlyPay = Double.parseDouble(input);


    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many hours have you worked this week?");
    double hoursWorked = Double.parseDouble(input);


    Employee richard = new Employee(employeeId, hoursWorked, hourlyPay);
    richard.displayWithholding();
    System.exit(0);
}


}
```

Comment: This may be a good learning opportunity to do TDD.

Comment: Standard debugging method:System.out.printf("Hourly rate: %f\n", hourlyPay);

Answer (score 0):

You're not calling getIncome until after calcWithHolding so the income variable is always zero during the calculation.

The current approach relies on side-effects from calling some of the accessors, this is generally considered to be a bad approach.

I would suggest one of the following

1. Ensure calculations done in the constructor (or called...)
2. Separate your concerns so that there is no confusion between data storage, object construction, data accessors and calculations.
3. Lazy initialization, so that calculated values are only calculated if they have never been accessed.